# how to convert a folder into an .exe file using powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, exe

I am working on a project,that needs a folder having some updated files and an .exe file of this folder so that when I share the .exe file to other team they should be able to read the content of the folder by extracting the .exe file.

I am new to powershell , I search over the internet but I did not found a suitable answer.

Comment: How about a zip file?

Comment: I knew about zip file creation ,but I need .exe file creation method or command  if any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this in Powershell natively. If you want to make a [self-extracting archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive), you can do this using different programs, for example [7-ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/). You have to download the program, and then, assuming it's in your path you can use it like this to create a self-extracting archive:
`7z.exe a -sfx <archive_name> <folder_name>`

If you want to integrate this into an existing powershell script, I would suggest you use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)